# Add Taxonomy Description with wp_set_post_terms

Tags: terms

I am adding tags during [wp_insert_post](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/) using [**wp_set_post_terms**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_set_post_terms/). But I have no clue how to add a tag description with my code. I have not found anything out there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `wp_set_post_terms()` to set the term description, but you can use [`wp_insert_term()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_term/) to create the term and set the description (plus other details), and then pass the term ID to `wp_set_post_terms()`.

Working example for one term:

```php
$taxonomy = 'category';
$term_name = 'Foo Bar';

// First we create the term (if it doesn't already exist).
if ( ! $term = term_exists( $term_name, $taxonomy ) ) {
    $term = wp_insert_term( $term_name, $taxonomy, array(
        'description' => 'Test category',
    ) );
}

// Now assign the term to the post (here the post ID is 1).
if ( $term && ! is_wp_error( $term ) ) {
    wp_set_post_terms( 1, $term['term_id'], $taxonomy );
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much! That solved my case!